# POST Errors PHP to dynamoDB

Tags: php, post

POST to DynamoDB for user login getting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException' with message 'Error
>   executing "GetItem" on "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS
>   HTTP error: Client error: `POST
>   https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad
>   Request` response:
>   {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema" (truncated...)
>   ValidationException (client): The provided key element does not match
>   the schema -
>   {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema"}'
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST
>   https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad
>   Request` response:
>   {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema" (truncated...) in
>   /var/www/html/sdks/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
>   Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sdks/vendor/guzz in
>   /var/www/html/sdks/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php
>   on line 192

MY PHP Code -----

```
    require 'config.php';
    use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

    $client = new DynamoDbClient([
        //'profile' => 'default', // access ID + secret are in the       .aws/credentials file
        'region' => 'us-east-1', // also tried with "eu-west-1"
        'version' => 'latest',
        'debug'  => true
    ]);
    // echo "after client instanciation"; // this is not displayed

    $username = null;
    $password = null;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if(!empty($_POST["userid"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
         $username = $_POST["userid"];
         $password = $_POST["password"];

         $response = $client->getItem(array(
             'TableName' => 'user',
             'Key' => array(
             'userid' => array( 'S' => $username),
             'password' => array( 'S' => $password),
         )
         ));

         if($username == 'userid' && $password == 'password') {
              session_start();
              $_SESSION["authenticated"] = 'true';
              header('Location: index.php');
         }
         //else {
              //header('Location: login.php');
         //}

    //} else {
         //header('Location: login.php');
    }

    print_r ($response['Item']);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your primary key (hash / partition key) is actually "userid", rather than "userid" + "password". As such, DynamoDB is telling you exactly that - whatever names you are using to pass to DynamoDB don't match up with what DynamoDB considers your primary key. I imagine once you take out the below line it will get closer to working for you:

```
'password' => array( 'S' => $password),
```

Just as an aside, you may want to securely store your passwords with some kind of algorithm - maybe `bcrypt` or similar. Otherwise your passwords are stored plain-text, which isn't considered a good practice these days.

Comment: Hello Steven -- Correct you are spot on the money .... i removed password and all is good.